# Incompatibility between two React Functional Component (FC) prop types with an object with any property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Not sure if I wrote a good title for the question. But, the code speaks for itself, considering the following:

```js
import { FC } from 'react'

type FCA = FC<{
  name: string
}>

type FCB = FC<{
  [key: string]: unknown
}>

const a: FCA = ({ name }) => {
  return null
}

const b: FCB =  a // ❌ TS error here
```

At the moment of defining the constant `b`, it shows the following TS error:

```
Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [key: string]: unknown; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }'.ts(2322)
```

How can I make it work without any TS error?

By the way, this works but the code from above doesn't:

```js
type A = {
  name: string
}

type B = {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

const a: A = { name: 'David' }

const b: B =  a // ✅ valid
```

It has something to do with the React FC type.

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are contravariant.

When you write `const b: B =  a`, TS checks that `{ name: string }` is assignable to `{ [key: string]: unknown }`, which is wider so everything is fine, but notice that in your error message, the two types are flipped. TS is checking that `{ [key: string]: unknown }` is assignable to `{ name: string }`, which it is not.

This is because your `FCB` type expects a function which is able to deal with any string keyed object, but you are passing in a function which can only deal with a subset of that: objects of type `{ name: string }`, so if it were to be called with, say `{ age: 42 }`, which satisfies `Parameters<FCB>`, it would explode at runtime.

Comment: I see. But, how can I achieve that behavior? Because we know that `{ name: string }` is assignable to `{ [key: string]: string }`.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What behaviour are you after? When constraining a function, one always has some contract in mind: "I'm going to call the function you provide with this specific type, so give me a function which can at least work with it, or more general if you like". If you are not in this kind of situation: at a boundary, in a higher order component, etc. you don't need to constrain the parameter. The module that owns an interface is the one which uses it